# Creating the secure store service master key fails

Tags: powershell, deployment

I have some powershell to create a farm including the secure store service.  The code is pretty straight forward:

```
Update-SPSecureStoreMasterKey -ServiceApplicationProxy $id -Passphrase $passphrase
```

I dont get any errors but when I then try to create an application server key, thus:

```
Update-SPSecureStoreApplicationServerKey -ServiceApplicationProxy $id -Passphrase $passphrase
```

it fails and tells me the master key is not found:

```
Update-SPSecureStoreApplicationServerKey : Master secret key is not present in the database.
```

The thing is, this doesnt always fail.  It's seems rather unreliable.

Anyone got a workaround or any clever ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same issue. I'm embarrased to admit I stopped investigating when I found that `Start-Sleep 5` seemed a reliable workaround.

```
Update-SPSecureStoreMasterKey -ServiceApplicationProxy $ssProxy -Passphrase xxx > $null
Start-Sleep 5
Update-SPSecureStoreApplicationServerKey -ServiceApplicationProxy $ssProxy -Passphrase xxx > $null
Start-Sleep 5
```

I guess theres a missing save/update/flush somewhere in those Cmdlets.

Not really a reasonable answer for a production quality solution but in my case I was trying to automate installation of our product for internal test purposes so a few sleeps were not a show-stopper.

Comment: We have the same issue with SP 2019 (at least in the case of the preview version). This workaround, waiting simply a few seconds, seems not to work in this case, but the solution proposed by @Davos helped us.

Answer (score 1):

"ChangeMasterSecretKey" from the instance of "Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.SecureStoreServiceApplication" fixed the issue for me: [SharePoint 2016 - Secure Store - MasterKey cannot be set! Problem Solved](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228821/sharepoint-2016-secure-store-masterkey-cannot-be-set-problem-solved)