# Secure Store Service Application showing status=error on CA>Manage Service Applications

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, central-administration, secure-store

Running SharePoint Server 2016 with MinRole.

- I looked on Manage services on server and Secure Store Service was
  Started and Compliant=Yes,
- also under Manage Service Applications, Secure Store Service
  Application Proxy Status=Started,
- so only the SSS Application is showing Status=Error

and I don't know why. I was unable to find any error related to this in Event Viewer in the Server neither.No failed jobs in Jobs History. Any ideas about why is this happening and how to change the status from Error to Started?

[image: SSS Error Status]

Comment: Have your tired to re-provisioned it again?

Comment: can you share the screen print (where it shows error)?

Comment: I also tried to run on the application server with the farm account `get-spsecurestoreapplication -name "Secure Store Service" -servicecontext https://myurl` and I got the error "unable to obtain master key". This is a production environment and I don't know for how long this has been with that error status.

Comment: Added a screenshot, but it is giving me an error when I click on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION: re-provision SSS (as Mohamed El-Qassas MVP suggested), but I discovered the following 2 prerequisites had to be met (which I was missing before):

1. Farm account has to be in the Admin group on both MinRole Servers.
2. Connect to App Server as the Farm account and run SharePoint Management Shell as Admin

   Run the cmdlets

   ```
   #As Status was stuck in Starting in Central Admin
   Get-SPServiceApplication | ?{$_ -match "Secure"}| select status #this returns Provisioning
   $sts = Get-SPServiceApplication | ?{$_ -match "Secure"}
   $sts.UnProvision() #this made Status=Stopped in Central Admin
   $sts.Provision() #this made Status=Started in Central Admin.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There are  several reasons why this may have happened.

Cause:   One or more of the following might be the cause:

1.The master encryption key was not generated after the Secure Store Service application was created.

2. The master encryption key was deleted.
3. The secure store database is corrupted.

You need to recreate master encryption key:

To create the master encryption key:

1. Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is a Service Application Administrator for the instance of the Secure Store Service.
2. Click the instance of the Secure Store Service application.
3. On the ribbon, click Generate New Key.
4. On the Generate New Key page, type a passphrase string in the Pass Phrase box, and type the same string in the Confirm Pass Phrase box.

REF:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server-2010/ee924660(v=office.14)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/835ab326-85db-41c1-9c2a-26371d1c905e/secure-store-service-unable-to-obtain-master-key?forum=appsforsharepoint

Comment: In my test farm, logged in as the Admin account, made it an Admin in the SSS application with Full Control and I keep getting error described here: [link](https://thesharepointfarm.com/2017/08/sharepoint-2016-secure-store-master-key-bug/)

Comment: I don't have operational experience with SP2016 so my advise was based on my SP2013 experiences. But it seems someone else on this forum hit your problem and manged to resolve it. Please check: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228821/sharepoint-2016-secure-store-masterkey-cannot-be-set-problem-solved

Comment: In the test farm I was able to Generate New Key when running Central Admin as System Account (Farm account) In production I keep getting the same error posted in my link above even with the Farm account.

Comment: Compare the permissions for the farm account (ie member of local admin group, different access to the config and service DBs) maybe there is a difference.

Comment: In production I found in the logs: `ChangeMasterSecretKey failed with exception: Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.SecureStoreServiceException: SecureStoreServiceApplication has not been provisioned and cannot be used`
then with the farm account (not server admin) I ran Mngmt Shell and called `$sts.Provision()` Got error `Access denied. Only Machine administrators are allowed to create administration service job definition of type: Microsoft.SharePoint....`.

Comment: 2 hours later I ran Mgmt Shell as the admin account (server admin) and `$sts.status= Provisioning`. In Central Admin, Secure Store Service Status = Starting. Not Error anymore. But as it was stuck with App status:"Provisioning" as the SP Admin account in Mngmt Shell I ran `$sts.UnProvision()`. In logs:  `Unprovisioning started for SecureStoreServiceApplication : Secure Store Service`. The status in Central Admin is stuck in Starting. Out of business hours I will try to see if clearing the config cache might help.

Comment: Clearing the config cache didn't help. SSS.Status keeps stuck in Starting.